# On Duplicate of entire rows of same values how to increase count?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a table using php mysql and using pdo for fetching records.

I want to know sql query so that if I insert row of all same values of same fields(duplicate row). It should insert new row by upgarding the count which is also one of the field

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, column4) 
   VALUES (value1, value2, value3,values4) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

this is hypothetical example
column2 is an id, which is foreign key constraints of another table2,
column3 is an id, which is foreign key constraints of another table3,
column4 is an id, which is foreign key constraints of another table4
total 4 tables I have. My table looks like this

```
 Sno  |  column2_id  |   column3_id  |  count | column4_id 
 1    |  column2_value  |   column3_value |  1 | column4_value
```

I have fetched all three tables data through id and show in table 1.

I have different values only 5 id in table 2 which have corresponding values.
if I insert new row of duplicate values it should insert by increasing count values.

```
By default I have taken count as 1.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand very well your request.
But if I understand correctly you want to update a row if it is duplicate?
If so you can just use an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

For example :

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, number) 
   VALUES (value1, value2, value3, number) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = number + 1;
```